# Steps involved to publish module on sitefinity marketplace

Tags: publish, add-on, sitefinity

I have an add-on or plugin for sitefinity cms. I just want to publish my add-on on their marketplace but I am not aware of the standards for the publishing the add-on as well as steps to publish it on marketplace. so, does anyone know the steps and standards for publishing plugin on SiteFinity marketplace.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some best practices on the Sitefinity Add-on submission page found here...
https://www.progress.com/sitefinity-cms/marketplace/submit-addon

Below is a link to the best practices recommended by Sitefinity...
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/best-practices-add-on-development

Other than that I recommend you contact them directly if you have questions by going to the URL below...
https://www.progress.com/company/contact?s=sitefinity

I wish it was a little more self-service, but unfortunately, it is not.

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Here is the updated marketplace page. there are forms for self submissions of add ons/integrations: https://www.progress.com/sitefinity-cms/marketplace